# using IF statement with leading zero comparison in Windows CMD

Tags: cmd

I found the below behaviour when using the IF statement with numeric values specified:

```
C:\> if 09 GEQ 1 echo YES
C:\>
```

I perfectly understand that in an alfabetical method, the above statement is false. But, all these are numbers, although one being prefixed with a zero, with is a mathematical unusual case. Still, it's a number.

The IF-help page says me:
(..) These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and
string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are
converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.
(..)

I think that case applies, since I only have numeric digits, and thus a numeric comparison should be applied, not an alphabetical.

Other comparisons work OK

```
C:\> if 09 GEQ 01 echo YES
C:\> YES

C:\> if 10 GEQ 1 echo YES
C:\> YES

C:\> if 9 GEQ 1 echo YES
C:\> YES

C:\> if 22 GEQ 5 echo YES
C:\> YES
```

What do you think ? Should the first IF statement posed, react that way. Or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Leading 0 on a number causes cmd.exe to interpret the number as an octal when using comparison or math (see `set /?`).

```
C:\>@if 012 EQU 10 echo Yes
Yes
```

Comment: That's interesting ... but 09 is not a valid number in the octal system. In that case, he should reply with a syntax error. I'm sure he reads "09" as an alfanumeric variable, and not as an octal. Also, what is the relevance of the SET help page for the IF command ? I know they have a relationship, but unless specified literally, that is meta info for the experts.

Comment: Lack of specific definitive documentation for cmd.exe is not new. Syntax error would probably break some stuff. You are probably correct that 09 is interpreted as text. But in any case I would recommend leaving cmd.exe behind and using PowerShell.

Comment: What is the biggest difference between CMD and PowerShell ?

Comment: They are completely separate. PowerShell is an entirely new command shell and scripting language based on the .NET Framework. There is plenty of information available about PowerShell [available by searching](http://bing.com/?q=what%20is%20powershell).

Comment: I asked the question hoping to get an answer that actually relates to the question in this thread. My question was actually : how would PowerShell prevent the issue of this thread, and because PS is better, how would it do that "better" ?

Comment: PowerShell uses .NET objects whereas cmd.exe works only with strings (that, under certain circumstances, can be interpreted as signed integers). PowerShell can work with .NET Int, Int32, UInt32, Double (etc.) number objects.

Answer (score -1):

By adding the `0` the IF treats the 09 as a string, which will cause and undefined result.

Remove the `0` to perform a numeric comparison.

Comment: I already stated in my opening post that I know that that is the cause of this behaviour, no need to repeat that. My question is different.